# Must replace Each() function in PHP code? Each() to foreach()

Tags: php

I must change the PHP version to 8.1 on a old code.

but i'm not sure that is right what i do.
old code:

```
    while (list($uhrzeit, $value) = each($wrdata)) 
    {
    $time_split = explode(":", $uhrzeit);
    $timestamp = mktime ($time_split[0], $time_split[1], $time_split[2], $month, $day, $year );
    $x1=$D->ScreenX( utcValue($timestamp-$intervall) );
    $x2=$D->ScreenX( utcValue($timestamp) );
    $x=$D->ScreenX( utcValue($timestamp-($intervall/2)) );
    if( $value>0 ) {
        $D->Bar($x1, $D->ScreenY($value), $x2, $D->ScreenY(0), "#FFFF00", "", "#FFFFFF", "$value W");
    }
```

new code:

```
    foreach ((Array) $wrdata as $uhrzeit => $value) 
    {
    $time_split = explode(":", $uhrzeit);
    $timestamp = mktime ($time_split[0], $time_split[1], $time_split[2], $month, $day, $year );
    $x1=$D->ScreenX( utcValue($timestamp-$intervall) );
    $x2=$D->ScreenX( utcValue($timestamp) );
    $x=$D->ScreenX( utcValue($timestamp-($intervall/2)) );
    if( $value>0 ) {
        $D->Bar($x1, $D->ScreenY($value), $x2, $D->ScreenY(0), "#FFFF00", "", "#FFFFFF", "$value W");
    }
```

Is that right to swap from the each() to foreach()?

Under PHP8.1 it does not work, but it could be that my problem is on a other place. Under PHP 7.4 all is fine

```
Warning: Undefined array key 1 in /homepages/43/d323078325/htdocs/solkal10.php on line 106
Warning: Undefined array key 2 in /homepages/43/d323078325/htdocs/solkal10.php on line 106

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mktime(): Argument #1 ($hour) must be of type int, string given in /homepages/43/d323078325/htdocs/solkal10.php:106 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/43/d323078325/htdocs/solkal10.php(106): mktime('', NULL, NULL, '12', '08', '10') #1 /homepages/43/d323078325/htdocs/solkal10.php(197): generatePic('./10/1208.png', '101208', 300, 15000, '8', '17') #2 {main} thrown in /homepages/43/d323078325/htdocs/solkal10.php on line 106
```

Comment: Have you tested the new code, does it produce the expected result?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct transformation.

Comment: Are you going to post a new question here for every change you have to make? Make your changes and test them. Ask here only if you are unable to make the changed code work.

Comment: under PHP8.1 it does not work, but it could be that my problem is on a other place. 
under PHP 7.4 all is fine

Comment: What have yout ried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If `explode` returns something different than before, why not check whether `$uhrzeit`  contains the same value?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of changes between PHP 5, 7 and 8. A great place to start for [8.1 is on the PHP page](https://www.php.net/migration81). Other mitigation version advice is also listed on that PHP page.

There is more than one change that has affected your posted code, and that is what is causing the confusion.

The `each()` to `foreach()` change is only one and has nothing to do with the posted error message (which is self explanatory).

`Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mktime(): Argument #1 ($hour) must be of type int...`

For that particular error, you can change:

```
$timestamp = mktime ($time_split[0], $time_split[1], $time_split[2], $month, $day, $year );
```

To

```
$timestamp = mktime((int)$time_split[0], (int)$time_split[1], $time_split[2], $month, $day, $year);
```

Why is this needed? Because [`explode(":", $uhrzeit);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) produced an array of `Strings`, which you then tried to use with [`mktime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), but `mktime()` requires `int` values.

Using `(int)$varible` will cast the `String` (or other type) value to an `int`.

There could be other error messages that follow once you fix that issue. Suggest you read the error message and cross check the PHP docs.